# Is it possible for a system of equations to have a non-zero determinant and no solution at the same time?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I am quite confused by the solution I was given for the following problems:

a) Solve the following system of equations using Gauss elimination only:

$2x - y = 5$

$-x + 2y = -4$

$3x - y = -1$

b) Based on part (a), what can you state about the relationship of vectors
$u = (2, -1, 3)$, $v = (-1, 2, -1)$, $w = (5, -4, -1)$?

c) What should the last co-ordinate of w be (the one which is currently -1) so that the behaviour of
the system of equations in (a) changes (i.e. if you found that it has no solutions, so that is now
has a unique solution; if you found it has a unique or infinite solutions, so that it now has no
solutions). Explain your answer.

The official solution I was given is this: http://screencast.com/t/FD3ZSPbUaL

Among the many problems I found with it, the one that confuses me the most is how it is possible for the determinant of the matrix to be non-zero (therefore the vectors to be independent) and the system to have no solution at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps you are putting in the final column to make a square. that is not how it works. The coefficient matrix is 3 by 2. There is no determinant. Or, as Leonard Cohen put it, $$\begin{array}{l}\text{You can add up the parts}\cr
\text{you won't have the sum}\cr
\text{You can strike up the march,}\cr
\text{there is no drum}\cr
\text{Every heart, every heart}\cr
\text{to love will come}\cr
\text{but like a refugee.}\end{array}$$

Comment: It appears my guess was correct, looking at your official solution. The 3 by 3 thing is sometimes called the augmented matrix, and you don't bother with the determinant of that.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't 'no solution' mean that the vectors should be linearly dependent?

Comment: Taking $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$ as the indicated column vectors, and real numbers $x,y,$ elimination shows you that $x \vec{u} + y \vec{v} = \vec{w}$ is impossible, meaning that those vectors are independent; so, put briefly, in this case you have the interpretation backwards.

Comment: Lastly, the final part of the official answers states that a unique solution corresponds to linearly dependent vectors and a zero determinant. I thought that a unique solution means linearly independent vectors and a non-zero determinant (apparently this is not always the case)?

Comment: I'm really sorry that they elected to use a determinant to answer the last part. It changes things, and is no quicker than the method I used in my answer. But yes, after putting in the replacement number 7, the three columns are now dependent vectors, so the 3 by 3 determinant is 0. The explicit dependence is that twice the first column minus the second column is the (revised) third column.

Comment: As they are dependent now, why aren't there an infinite number of solutions, but just a unique one? I'm sorry I don't completely understand this  yet, it seems all I know about linear independence  is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I suggest you get individual tutoring, sooner rather than later. There is not that much I can teach you at a distance, concentrating on a single problem. Sometimes students join with a few classmates in study groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$   
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  2  &  -1   \\
  -1   &  2   \\
  3  &  -1     
\end{array} 
  \right)  \; \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{r}
  x   \\
  y    
\end{array} 
  \right)  \; = \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{r}
  5   \\
  -4 \\
-1    
\end{array} 
  \right) 
  $$

I see, in the final question you could combine into a 3 by 3 matrix to most quickly alter that last entry. Sigh.

Not how i would do the final part; it is easy enough to invert and solve a 2 by 2 system, finding out what $x,y$ must be, leading to
$$   
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  2  &  -1   \\
  -1   &  2   \\
  3  &  -1     
\end{array} 
  \right)  \; \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{r}
  2   \\
  -1    
\end{array} 
  \right)  \; = \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{r}
  5   \\
  -4 \\
?    
\end{array} 
  \right) 
  $$
after which we calculate
$$   
 \left(  \begin{array}{rr}
  2  &  -1   \\
  -1   &  2   \\
  3  &  -1     
\end{array} 
  \right)  \; \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{r}
  2   \\
  -1    
\end{array} 
  \right)  \; = \;
 \left(  \begin{array}{r}
  5   \\
  -4 \\
7   
\end{array} 
  \right) 
  $$